# type parameter to take more than one type

Tags: scala

I have the below trait and I want constants to have more than one type parameter

```
trait MyTrait[+A]  {

  val value: A

}

object Currency {

  sealed trait MyConstants extends MyTrait[String]

  case object A extends MyConstants {val value ="abc"}

  //etc.
  case object B extends MyConstants {val value = "def"}

  //etc.

  val list = Seq(A, B)


}
```

I want to create another `case object C extends MyConstants {val value = 10}`

Can anyone suggest a way to make a type parameter take `Int or String` as types

Comment: Maybe just  `case object C extends MyTrait[Int] { val value = 42 }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not parameterize `MyConstants` itself?

```
sealed trait MyConstants[T] extends MyTrait[T]

case object A extends MyConstants[String] {val value ="abc"}

case object B extends MyConstants[Int] {val value = 10}
```

Comment: In case I have `def getValue(value: String): Option[MyConstants] = list.find(_.value == value)` how will I use it as I need to check for both int and string

Comment: @coder25 You can have `def getValue[T](value: T): Option[MyConstants[T]]` and define the type when invoking. You can even omit the explicit type annotation, compiler will infer it, e.g. `getValue("asdf")` will work just fine (explicit would be `getValue[String]("asdf")`

Comment: `def getValue[T](value: T): Option[MyConstants[T]] = list.find(_.value == value)`.It gives compile error

Comment: Solution I provided is OK, but it's not a silver bullet that will allow you to mix types and retain type information. List of `MyConstants[String]` and `MyConstants[Int]` will result in list of `MyConstants[Any]`. If you can't go around this kind of heterogenous list, then take a look at shapeless [HList](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists) which allows you to retain type info.